# Javascript if else loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

I'm sure there probably is, however I'm not sure what it's called so apologises if this is something super similar. I'm wondering if there's a faster way to code the following:

```
var b = "#ff0002";
var o = "#46c029";
var i = "#f2ec00";
var n = "#f64c98";
var g = "#52c6f3";

if(a==1){
    return b;
}else if(a==2){
    return o;
}else if(a==3){
    return i;
}else if(a==4){
    return n;
}else if(a==5){
    return g;
}
```

Comment: It's called a switch statement.  Or potentially a lookup map would also work.

Comment: There's no loop here. Loops are `for` and `while`, where you do something repeatedly until some ending condition is met.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, lookup array:

```
return [b, o, i, n, g][a - 1];
```

Not necessarily faster, but definetly shorter :)

Comment: Amazing! So much cleaner, thank you. Yeah, I wasn't expecting it to be faster but knew it could be clean

Comment: @liam glad to help :)

Comment: any reason the first letter wouldn't be getting a colour set? :/ I've included the entire script in case it's being caused by a different issue

Comment: @liam in your original question, `a` was 1 to get `b`, but now your `count` starts with `0`, in that case, just remove the `- 1`

Comment: @liam no worries :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have large number of strings to compare from use `Object` like this:

```js
myObj = {1: '#ff0002', 2: '#46c029', 3: "#f2ec00", 4: "#f64c98", 5: "#52c6f3"}

console.log(myObj[3]);
```

If you are using `ES6` you can use [`Map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) like this:

```js
const myMap = new Map([[1, '#ff0002'], [2, '#46c029'], [3, "#f2ec00"], [4, "#f64c98"], [5, "#52c6f3"]])

console.log(myMap.get(3)); // or any key
```

Comment: But what about 'boing' :P Nah, if this is actually faster I'd be interested, otherwise it's a lengthier script

Comment: @Liam if you don't have large number of strings/comparison go with the Jonas W's solution.

Comment: No worries, thank you! This is handy though as I started this thread to cover my future tracks when I expand into more numbers